# Information about LF+CR and Windows coding vs Linux coding for Perl programming

Tags: linux, perl

I have perl script which works fine in windows. But when I try to run this in Mac OS X, it doesn't perform full task. Can anyone make explanation of LF+CR? Why these line endings don't work on Unix? & in that case what to do with the perl script written for windows if I want to run it in Linux/Unix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755553/carriage-return-and-line-feed-windows-and-linux-java-application *You can check the line separator for the host operating system using System.getProperty("line.separator")*  (whatever the equivalent is in perl)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11391721

Comment: Thanks I have read those articles and trying to do something different with my codes. Don't know will it work or not but I love this forum because everyone so active and try to respond so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a file containing the following bytes:

```
61 62 63 0D 0A 64 65 66 0D 0A
```

By Windows definition of a text file, that file has two lines consisting of `61 62 63` and `64 65 66` plus the line terminator.

By unix's definition of a text file (including Mac's), that file has two lines consisting of `61 62 63 0D` and `64 65 66 0D` plus the line terminator.

Since the lines are different, of course they don't work the same.

If you are on a unix system and you want two lines consisting of `61 62 63` and `64 65 66` plus the line terminator, the file will need to consist of the following bytes:

```
61 62 63 0A 64 65 66 0A
```

You can use `dos2unix` to translate Windows text files into unix text files.

Answer (score 1):

You could use perl to change windows line endings (\r\n) to line feeds (\n):

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n?/\n/g' your-script.pl
```

By making the newline character optional, this can also convert legacy mac line endings (\r) to line feeds. You could make it an alias:

```
alias fixlines="perl -pi -e 's/\r\n?/\n/g'"
```