# Java AWT line break in TexArea

Tags: java, awt, textarea

Is it possible to make a line break in a TextArea? Using \r\n helps but it works on Windows only. I also want it work on Ubuntu and Mac. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the usual `\n` in linux and didn't work?

In a universal solution consider using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as separator.

Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755553/carriage-return-and-line-feed-windows-and-linux-java-application)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to find out the line break String on the platform.